# How can I append html to a found selector in an HTML string with jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to append a node to a found jQuery object that was found with a selector, which is in this case an id (selector, e.g. `#emp1-day3`), in a string (contents) but the append function does not append to the found jQuery object even if `$(contents).find(selector)`returns the right jQuery object.

```
var nodeWorkShift = $('<div>' + stringWorkShift + '</div>');
$(contents).find(selector).append(nodeWorkShift);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `contents` is a string then your code effectively doesn't do anything as the created and modified collection is thrown away. You need to store the collection.

```
var nodeWorkShift = $('<div>' + stringWorkShift + '</div>');
var $contents = $(contents).find(selector).append(nodeWorkShift).end();
// string representation of the collection
console.log( $contents.prop('outerHTML') );
```